# test web-services with netbeans

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jax-rs, jackson

I'm new to webservices and i want to know what i'm doing wrong here's my code to get all my listCustomers

```
@Path("/allCustomers")
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public List<Customer> listAllCustomers(){
    return customerDao.listAllCustomers();
}
```

To test my services i use netbeans tool (TEST RESTFUL web services) and i'm getting this error

```
 Avertissement: StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for  servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.supinfo.supinbank.service.CustomerService.listAllCustomers(CustomerService.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

PS: I don't know if it's mandatory to annotate Customer Entity with XmlRootElement but i did it ...

Comment: could you post the lines 40 to 50 of your CustomerService class?

Comment: The lines 40-50 are those post before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search i just find a lazy method to auto create webservices with netbeans.
First, i create a simple web services by annotate my class with @WebService and my method with @WebMethod . Then i just right click in my services and generate restful service with netbeans the result looks like this :

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Path("listallcustomers/")
public JAXBElement<ListAllCustomersResponse> getListAllCustomers() {
    try {
        // Call Web Service Operation
        if (port != null) {
            java.util.List<com.supinfo.supinbank.service_client.Customer> result = port.listAllCustomers();

            class ListAllCustomersResponse_1 extends com.supinfo.supinbank.service_client.ListAllCustomersResponse {

                ListAllCustomersResponse_1(java.util.List<com.supinfo.supinbank.service_client.Customer> _return) {
                    this._return = _return;
                }
            }
            com.supinfo.supinbank.service_client.ListAllCustomersResponse response = new ListAllCustomersResponse_1(result);
            return new com.supinfo.supinbank.service_client.ObjectFactory().createListAllCustomersResponse(response);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO handle custom exceptions here
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now it work great...

Answer (score 0):

The excepion is NullPointerException that means that your object customerDao is null, that is the reason of your problem.

Comment: i don't think so, because if i call my method from an internal class i get a list of customers.